# How do I automatically cluster an asymmetric dependency matrix?

Tags: c#, algorithm, matrix

I’ve created a matrix to show dependencies between stored procedures and tables. It distinguishes between inserts/updates/deletes, represented with a U, and selects, represented with an R.

Here’s an example:
[dependency matrix](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3DrB3.png)

I want to automatically cluster this asymmetric matrix, to have a better insight in the tables that are often updated/read together, and stored procedures that update/read the same tables. The U should take precedence over the R, but if they’re valued equally, I can work with that.

The result should look like this figure:
[clustered matrix](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XySVH.png)

I’ve created a simple algorithm that counts pairs of tables that are updated together frequently, stored procedures that update the same table frequently and reorder the matrix based on occurrence of these pairs.

The result isn’t great though. So, I’m looking for a code example of an algorithm that can provide a better result. C# would be great, but another language is fine too. A .NET library would be even better.

Comment: How big are these matrices? What about simply try all row/column combinations to find the best one?

Comment: In this case it's 500 (tables) x 900 (stored procedures) with quit a few dependencies between them.  

Your suggestion to try all row/column combinations is kind of what I'm already doing by counting pairs and ordering on those. The result is OK but not very clever. I'm hoping for an algorithm that provides a better result.